# How can I use Psconsole.psc1 -Command Get-{anything}

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am working with Powershell scripts that are all executed this way:

```
PS C:\long\path\to\Psconsole.psc1  -Command  {Get-whatever...}
```

They all generate the error:

`You must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the value '-' operator.`*

Here's an example:

```
PS  C:\>  "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\psconsole.psc1" -Command "Get-Service"
```

Same error message:

```
`You must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the value '-' operator.`
... At line 1...
 - <<< Command "Get-Service"
  + CategoryInfo:         PaserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  + FullyQualifiedError:   ExpectedValueExpression
```

Can anyone tell me a way to get the -Command working?

Answer (score 0):

By enclosing your path in quotes, you're telling PowerShell that it is a string and then the - before "-Command" is interpreted as an operator not a parameter.

To get around this, prefix your statement with the "Call" operator "&":

```
 & "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\psconsole.psc1" -Command "Get-Service"
```

EDIT:  If you use the Tab key for autocompletion of the path, the Console would automatically put the & Call operator there for you when it sees the space in the full path.

Comment: That call operator fixed the error.  Thanks.  Now the command creates a powershell window.  However, it does not execute the command in it.  This might be adequate for my needs (gotta test more), but just wanted to warn other readers.